# ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ObjID failed because one or more objects access this column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

In Entity Framework code first, I simply changed a `char` primary key column from `char(41)` to `char(42)` using the `dotnet ef migrations add ChangedObjIDLen` console command. This created the following, very simple update script:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace DE.ZA.MobilePickingApp.Migrations
{
    public partial class ChangedObjIDLen : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "ObjID",
                table: "CustomFields",
                type: "char(42)",
                maxLength: 42,
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(string),
                oldType: "char(41)",
                oldMaxLength: 41);
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "ObjID",
                table: "CustomFields",
                type: "char(41)",
                maxLength: 41,
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(string),
                oldType: "char(42)",
                oldMaxLength: 42);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the class code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DE.ZA.MobilePickingApp.Model.Database {
    public class CustomFields {
        [Key, StringLength(42, MinimumLength = 42), Column(TypeName = "char(42)"), JsonIgnore]
        public string ObjID { get; set; }

        public bool ItemInProcess { get; set; }

        public string Remarks { get; set; }

        public bool Retrieved { get; set; }

        public bool Commissioned { get; set; }


        [NotMapped]
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> _EditableFields;

        static CustomFields() {
            _EditableFields = typeof(CustomFields)
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(p => p.Name != "ObjID")
                .ToDictionary(p => p.Name.ToLower(), p => p);
        }

        public static bool IsFieldEditable(string fieldName) {
            return _EditableFields.Keys.Contains(fieldName.ToLower());
        }

        internal void SetValue(KeyValuePair<string, object> entry) {
            PropertyInfo p;

            if (!_EditableFields.TryGetValue(entry.Key.ToLower(), out p))
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid key");

            p.SetValue(this, entry.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

However, as soon as I try to apply this migration to the database using `dotnet ef database update`, I get the following error:

> The object 'PK_CustomFields' is dependent on column 'ObjID'.
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ObjID failed because one or more objects access this column.

How can I get rid of that?

Comment: Did you change all the columns that foreign-key to it to `char(42)` as well?

Comment: @madreflection There is no foreign key to this column.

Comment: Is there a `CHECK` constraint? Or a view with schemabinding?

Comment: @marc_s Nope, the table stands for itself. I'll add te c# code of the class to my question.

Comment: The problem is: if that column is the **primary key** of your table, it's used in the **primary key constraint** - that's what the error is referring to. If you did this in raw SQL, you'd have to first drop the PK constraint, alter the table, and then re-create the PK constraint. Not sure how to handle this in EF migrations ....

Comment: You probably need to add a `.DropPrimaryKey()` before altering the column, and re-add the primary key using `.AddPrimaryKey()` after you've modified the column size. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.dropprimarykey?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Comment: @marc_s Those migration scripts are generated automatically. I can modify them for sure, but I wonder, if I made some mistake as they usually work without manual intervention.

Comment: Same here - I would have expected that EF would detect the fact that this column is the primary key, and handle all of this automatically.....

Comment: @marc_s Adjusting the up/down migrations as you described solved my problem perfectly, and yes, I would also expect EF to handle this technicality automatically.  Other tooling does.